# How can I solve this first order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the solution of this differential equation? 
$$y'(x)=(x+2)y(x)-xy(x)^3$$

Comment: It's Bernoulli's equation. What have you tried ?

Comment: No I haven't but I will thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation

Comment: Can you show us what you have done? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Thanks  @Fakemistake I was edting while you were commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y'=(x+2)y-xy^3$$
It's Bernoulli's equation. Divide by $y^3$:
$$\dfrac {y'}{y^3}=\dfrac {(x+2)}{y^2}-x$$
Substitute $u=\dfrac 1 {y^2}$ . The equation becomes a first order linear DE.
$$-\frac 12u'= {(x+2)}u-x$$